# Passing more multiple queries in a View ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my Repository class I have this two queries that I want it to appear in just one view:

```
public ClassXXXX GetxxxoList(string Name)
{
    return context.ClassXXXX.Where(v => v.Name == Name).Single();
}
```

And the second query in Repository class I have:

```
public IEnumerable<ClassXXXX> List()
{
    return context.ClassXXXX.ToList();
}
```

Then in my view I am doing this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Namespace.Models.ClassXXXX>

@model Namespace.Models.ClassXXXX
```

To return the two queries in my view respectively.
But ASP.NET throws exception on using @model twice in just one view.

Comment: I have no clue what you want or what your doing.

Comment: create common model, model = new YourModel { SingleObject = context.ClassXXXX.Where(v => v.Name == Name).Single(), MassObject = context.ClassXXXX.ToList() }

Comment: Hi Igor, tried using your approach but it tells me that SingleObject or MassObject is undefined. The model you mean in this context are you referring to a method to be created in a repository class or an entire new class.

Answer (score 1):

instead of:

```
@model IEnumerable<Namespace.Models.ClassXXXX>
@model Namespace.Models.ClassXXXX
```

You can create an ViewModel class, that contains all your needed data:

```
public class YourContextViewModel
{
    public List<Person> Person { get; set; }
    public string UserName{get;set;}
    ...
}
```

It's a good idea to create an ViewModel object to populate your views.

Comment: This is the proper way.  You could also pass it in via ViewData, but this method is the most proper way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

Create a new model that encapsulates both models. Create the model ModelXXXX in the Models namespace

```
public class ModelXXXX
{
    public ModelXXXX(ClassXXXX singleXXXX, List<SingleXXXX> listXXXX)
    {
        SingleXXXX = singleXXXX;
        ListXXXX = listXXXX;
    }

    public ClassXXXX SingleXXXX { get; set; };
    public IList<ClassXXXX> ListXXXX { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller you would have something like:

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()     
{
    [...]
    string name = "name";
    ModelXXXX model = new ModelXXXX(GetxxxoList(name), List());

    return View("..Views/Index.cshtml", model)
}
```

And finally in the view you would have:

```
@model Namespace.Models.ModelXXXX

[...]
@Model.SingleXXXX 
@Model.ListXXXX
```

The first one (@Model.SingleXXXX) will have the value of @model Namespace.Models.ClassXXXX

And the second one (@Model.SingleXXXX) will have the value of @model IEnumerable

Comment: Hi Petrov, I just have one Model whose name is classXXX. I am using this classXXX to define two queries in my repo class and returning it in my view class

Comment: Hi Patrick, I don't think it is possible to use _model_ more than once in a single view. That's why I have suggested using a model to hold both of them. So you might have 
new ModelXXXX { SingleXXXX = GetxxxoList(name), ListXXXX = List()}; 
Pass this model to the View, and the view will use Model <path>.ModelXXXX and in the view you can use Model.SingleXXXX and Model.ListXXXX

Comment: Hi @PatrickNdu, I have edited my answer to make it more clear, I hope it helps.

Comment: I do agree with @SvetoslavPetrov  but you also can have model which contains only IList<ClassXXXX> and set ViewBag property inside controller to ClassXXXX from the second method and then use this ViewBag in the View

Comment: Thanks Petrov. Well explained.